# JRuby + Nokogiri: Not retrieving URL content

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri, jrubyonrails

I'm using JRuby 1.6.2 and Nokogiri (1.5.0.beta.4). When I execute the following code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=tenderlove'
puts "Retrieving: " + url
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
puts doc
```

I get the following results:

```
Retrieving: http://www.google.com/search?q=tenderlove
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
```

However, in reality, that particular URL contains Google search results.

When I run the same code with Ruby 1.8.7 and nokogiri, I get HTML containing the expected results.

Any ideas on why Nokogiri is not returning the expected content? Tips on fixing it?

Comment: This isn't a Nokogiri problem. The data being retrieved is being passed from OpenURI, before Nokogiri sees it.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335877/nokogiri-html-parsing-not-working