# Nokogiri HTML parsing not working

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to parse some HTML with Nokogiri, but I am not getting anything back from the `css` or `xpath` methods.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.google.com"))
doc.css('div').each do |div|
   puts div.content
end
doc.xpath('//div').each do |div|
   puts div.content
end
```

Nothing gets printed to the screen, so `css` and `xpath` are returning empty arrays. There are at least 100 divs in Google's homepage.

`doc.to_html` returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>\n\n
```

`doc.validate` returns:

```
[#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: no root element>]
```

---

I uninstalled Nokogiri, and reinstalled libxml2 and libxslt as mentioned in "[Installing Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html)". Everything's working now.

Comment: It works fine. I've just tried it in my terminal. Are you sure you're not having other kind of issues? For example, try to change site...

Comment: Same here. Try reinstalling the gem.

Comment: Uninstalled and reinstalled the gem - still not working. I'm using RVM and ruby 1.9.2. When I do gem list - I can see "nokogiri (1.5.0)"

Comment: Interesting - when I try doc.validate - I get this message: "[#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: no root element>]". Is this normal?

Also - doc.to_html returns "<!DOCTYPE html>\n\n"

Comment: Working for me too in irb. Try it step by step and see where is it failing

Comment: You may have a connection problem, suchas requiring a proxy. There are mechanize.agent functions available to solve that.

Comment: "I uninstalled Nokogiri, and reinstalled libxml2 and libxslt as mentioned in "Installing Nokogiri". Everything's working now." should be a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), not an [edit to the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387912/can-should-i-edit-my-question-to-an-add-answer).